# Hilt dependencies not provided in tests

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

I'm was starting to using `hilt` and I ran into a problem while testing.

This is the code that is generating the following error:

```
@HiltAndroidTest
@RunWith(CommonUiRunner::class)
class PhoneEditTextTest {

    @Test
    fun testThatNumberFormatted() {
        val controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(AppCompatActivity::class.java)
        val activity = controller.get()
        val editText = PhoneEditText(activity)

        activity.setContentView(editText)
        controller.setup()
    }
}

@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object ApplicationModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providePhoneNumberUtil(app: Application): PhoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.createInstance(AssetsMetadataLoader(app.assets))
}

@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object CountriesFeatureModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesApi(app: Application): CountriesFeatureApi = CountriesFeatureImpl(app.assets)
}
```

Returning:

`APPLICATION and COUNTRIES-FEATURE modules contains in INJECTOR gradle-module.`

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot use normal Activities when you want to test dagger-hilt stuff.

Please look at the following tutorial as it should solve your problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4zG93ogWFY&t